# Why will PHPUnit not accept an XML defined test suite?

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I'm following along on the [`ZendCast`](http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-models/2010/10/) for writing unit tests on top of the Zend Framework. Between the video and a few other sources, my `phpunit.xml` looks like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="./application/bootstrap.php" colors="true">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="RefreshTests">
            <directory>./</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../application</directory>
        </whitelist>
        <exclude></exclude>
    </filter>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/report" charset="UTF-8"
        yui="true" highlight="true" lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80" />
        <log type="testdox" target="./log/testdox.html" />
    </logging>

</phpunit>
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run PHPUnit with this file, while I can verify that the "boostrap.php" file does, run, I get this error at runtime:

> PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Neither "RefreshTests.php" nor "RefreshTests.php" could be opened. in C:\Program Files (x86)\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Skeleton\Test.php on line 102

This seems to indicate that PHPUnit is looking for a file based on what I named the test suite in order to find the tests to run, instead of respecting my wishes to have it run against the entire directory. This despite that [PHPUnit's documentation quite explicitly says that defining a test suite this way is allowed.](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests.xml-configuration)

What have I done incorrectly?

Comment: May be a windows issue. What version of phpunit are you using? Pear distribution might be out of date as well

Comment: error looks like that the path to the tests is not correct, or no tests are available (do you have files with Prefix Test?, e.g. ClassTest.php?)

Comment: Yeah can you put the files on github?

Comment: @Tim: Unfortunately, no, I can't. Gah! This is so much easier to ask about when one is working on his or her own stuff :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that phpunit can't find any test class within the `"."` directory while scanning it recursively.

If it can't find any test files it then tries to open a .php file named like the testsuite. Hence the error.

Make sure your TestClasses end in `Test.php` or add a `suffix=".php"`(or whatever) to your `<directory>` tag and make sure that file contains a class that also ends in `Test`.